# TeX and Ubuntu coming from OS-X

Tags: texlive, ubuntu

I'm new to Ubuntu (using 12.04) coming from OS-X 10.8 and .9.

I've been using LaTeX on OS-X using the TeXWorks editor.  When I tried to install TeXLive on Ubuntu 12.4 it seems to have installed okay (at least, Synaptic insists it is installed) but I can't find TeX anywhere.

Do I have to use a not-TeX-aware to get to TeX (and Lilypond, etc)?  Or do I have to change away from Unity?

I know this is a really low-level question, but I'm a little flummoxed at this point.  What is the point of a desktop environment if everything has to be done via scripts?

Comment: Welcome to the site! It's typically best to follow the instructions in [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092) Having said that, you can test if you have `TeX` and friends installed by opening up a terminal and typing `tex` or `pdflatex` followed by return

Comment: Although not being a friend of such TeX-IDEs, how about `TeXMaker` if you prefer a graphical interface?

Comment: Synaptic probably isn't lying.  Try typing `which tex` in a terminal to confirm that it is installed.  The next question is then: which editor to use?  There are dozens of editors, including (according to Apt) one called 'texworks', which you should be able to install using Synaptic or, via command line, `sudo apt-get install texworks`.  Whether that one is the same as the OSX one, however, I don't know.  My unasked for advice is: use Emacs (with AUCTeX).

Comment: The OP is probably looking for a TeX Live entry in the menu. @user48148 do you know how to open a terminal? Look for it in the menus or search for it using the dash. Once you open it, what is the output of `pdflatex --version` ?

Comment: To all:  Thanks for the assistance.  TeX is in fact installed.  I've installed TeXMaker and it all seems to be working now.  I use TeXMaker on my Macs, but that doesn't seem to be available on Ubuntu.  @jon:  As far as emacs goes, I'm a little leery of it but I suppose I ought to get over that.

Comment: The command `apt-cache search texmaker` returns this line (among others): `texmaker - cross-platform LaTeX editor`.  Have you tried to install it; e.g., `apt-get install texmaker`.  But as to whether that 'texmaker' is similar enough to the OSX one, I have no idea.  My suggstion: use what you like/know for now, but install Emacs (and AUCTeX) anyway and fiddle with it once in a while.  Once you become familiar with how it works and all it can do for you, you may well become a convert....

Comment: @ jon: I really need to learn to read what I write.  I'm using TeXShop on the Macs.  I have installed the Unity version of TeXMaker, which is how I got TeX running on Satchel.